# How can I send feedback with Testflight Android?

Tags: android, sdk, testflight

The TestFlight SDK for iOS has a `submitFeedback` method, so the user can give feedback from within the app and the feedback will show up on TestFlight for that specific build.

I cannot seem to find an equivalent method in the Android version of the SDK.

I know I can use the feedback e-mail address shown on the TestFlight page for the app build, but is there really no way to do this via the SDK?

Comment: Nope, it would seem the only way to send feedback for Android app is to use the email address specified on the build page...

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the feedback. We will add this feature soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TestFlight is dropping Android support](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1450414), so this will probably not be fixed.

Ended up using [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net) instead, which supports iOS, Android and Windows Phone.